# The type or namespace name "ContentBySearchWebPart" could not be found

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

[image]

Recently, I was trying to add a Content Search Web Part using csom in Visual Studio 2017, While I was adding the "ContentBySearchWebPart" class, an error occured as: 
**"The type or namespace name "ContentBySearchWebPart" could not be found(you are missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".**
Even I was using the namespace as "**Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls**" and also the "**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search**" dll. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll" manually from ISAPI folder or GAC

ISAPI folder

```
<Windows>\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extenstions\16\ISAPI
```

GAC

`(C:\windows\Windows.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search).`

Namespace:  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls
Assembly:  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search (in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c6f03ea3-f893-4126-88e3-52a2a66b5f18/missing-assembly-reference-for-microsoftofficeserversearch?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Check your \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extenstions\14\ISAPI, you'll find alot more DLL's inside this folder including your Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll that you are looking for.

Comment: Here actually I am using client side object model csom, not server side code. Is there any client dll is there?

Comment: here are all dlls for online csom ¨https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM